# Elasticsearch cluster data migration

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 10 nodes in one cluster(in a server). I want to dump all documents from this cluster. After that, import these docs to new cluster. The new cluster will be have only one node.
I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CX7wrB56deI)

After naming the snapshot. I have files. Then I create new cluster with same name and tried to import it. With below code

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/esbackup/first-snapshot/_restore?wait_for_completion=true'
```

But this code didn't work fine.

**How can i migrate data from one cluster to new one ?**

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

there is a simpler solution for your problem.
try to exclude nine node from your cluster.

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : ["10.0.0.1","10.1.1.2","10.1.1.3"]
  }
}
```

then after you are assured that all indices moved to first node. then stop services in all 9 node (one bye one). I recommend you increase heap size of first node, before exclude command.

Comment: do you have one master in your cluster?  if you have more than one, open a new question about how to decrease number of master node to one without downtime in  cluster.